# Consequences of No Cleanups After os._exit()

Tags: python, operating-system

I have been reading a bit about `os._exit(n)` and have found most of the answers here stating something like:

> "Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc."

I was wondering what exactly are the consequences of such an exit. We are terminating the execution of the program anyway, so:

1. What if we do not call cleanup handlers of objects?
2. What if we do not flush stdio buffers?
3. Any other operation that would happen, along with their reasoning.

The program has anyway finished execution. So why even (this may sound naïve) bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the documentation says, calling `os._exit(n)` bypasses any cleanup handlers such as flushing stdio buffers, so the following code:

```
import os
import sys

print('a', end='')
os._exit(0)
```

outputs nothing, but if you replace `os._exit(0)` with `sys.exit(0)` it would then output `a`.

Similarly, calling `os._exit(n)` bypasses exit handler functions registered with [`atexit.register`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#atexit.register), so the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import atexit

class BufferedPrint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.texts = []

    def buffer(self, text):
        self.texts.append(text)

    def print(self):
        print(*self.texts, sep='\n')

buffered_print = BufferedPrint()
atexit.register(buffered_print.print)
buffered_print.buffer('foo')
buffered_print.buffer('bar')
os._exit(0)
```

outputs nothing, but if you replace `os._exit(0)` with `sys.exit(0)` it would then output:

```
foo
bar
```

Cleanups may or may not be consequential depending on the nature of the cleanup tasks. If you bypass the cleanup of a database connection maintained by a client object, for example, the database connection may end up lingering around for a lot longer than if you let the cleanup handler clean it up actively, while in the mean time the zombie connection takes up system resources on both ends. It is up to you to decide if a specific cleanup task matters or not.

Comment: I read up more on "flushing I/O buffers" and have a better understanding of it now. The example really helps. With respect to the last part of your answer, could you suggest some references that illustrate more examples? Lingering database connections make sense, now that I think of it. What other cases could there be, I wonder?